# Question on Update pannel

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

i am using a asp.net updatepannel .Will update panel create a div in the client side ?

Comment: One guess on the best way to answer that question.  (Hint: it's not by asking a question on SO)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

In the future try a right-click > view source.

Answer (score 0):

by default, yes

but is you set `RenderMode="Inline"` it will create a `<span>`